# ¿Cómo puedo crear un árbol No-Binario en C++?

Tags: c++, tree

Tengo que crear un arbol que no sea binario, para que cada nodo pueda tener mas de dos hijos, de momento solo se crear uno binario utilizando estructuras:

```
struct Dato{
    int numero;
    string nombre;
};

struct nodo{
    Dato dato;
    nodo *der;
    nodo *izq;
};
```

y luego la creacion del nodo:

```
nodo *crearNodo(Dato n){
    nodo *NuevoNodo = new nodo();
    NuevoNodo->dato = n;
    NuevoNodo->der = NULL;
    NuevoNodo->izq = NULL;
    
    return NuevoNodo;
}

void agregarNodo(nodo *&arbol, Dato n){
    if(arbol == NULL){//verificando que arbol este vacio.
        nodo *nuevoNodo = crearNodo(n);//agregando la raiz al nuevo nodo.
        arbol = nuevoNodo;
        
        cout<<("Nodo raiz creado")<<endl;
    }else{
        Persona ValorDeRaiz = arbol->dato;//Es para saber que valor tiene la RAIZ.
        if(n.numero < ValorDeRaiz.numero){//Cuando el Valor es menor va al lado izquierdo.
            agregarNodo(arbol->izq,n);//Agregando al lado izquierdo.
            cout<<("Nodo izquierdo creado")<<endl;
        }else{
            agregarNodo(arbol->der,n);//Agregando al lado derecho.
            cout<<("Nodo derecho creado")<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Como se puede observar esto solo me sirve para un arbol con maximo dos hijos por nodo, no se como crearlo para que cada nodo tenga mas de dos hijos (n cantidad).

esto con el objetivo de representar un arbol genealogico.

Answer (score 1):

Un árbol no binario puede tener cualquier cantidad de hijos. Eso implica usar alguna estructura para almacenar los hijos.

Hay 2 opciones simples.

- Usar un arreglo, con un máximo de elementos arbitrario y una variable que lleve la cuenta:

  ```
  struct nodo {
      Dato dato;
      int nRamas;
      nodo *ramas[64];
  };
  ```
- Usar algún [contenedor de la librería estándar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). Por ejemplo [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

  ```
  struct nodo {
      Dato dato;
      vector<nodo*> ramas;
  };
  ```

La implementación de las funciones es similar a la de árboles binarios. Así que te lo dejo como tarea.

---

Por cierto, estás en C++, puedes agregar constructores para facilitarte la vida. Incluso puedes usar plantillas para poder generar un árbol de cualquier tipo. Un ejemplo con el primer caso:

```
template <typename T>
struct nodo {
    T dato;
    int nRamas;
    nodo<T> *ramas[64] = {};

    // Constructor por defecto.
    // Delega la construcción al otro constructor con dato = 0
    nodo() : nodo(0) {
          
    }

    nodo(T _dato) : dato(_dato), nRamas(0), ramas{}{
          
    }
};
```

Así no necesitas la función `crearNodo`. Solo tienes que usar el operador `new` con los parámetros del constructor en uso.

```
// Llama al constructor por defecto
nodo<int> *nodo1 = new nodo<int>;
// Llama al constructor correspondiente
nodo<int> *nodo2 = new nodo<int>(10);
```